# Pre-compiled Azure Function with IBinder fails with "No binding found for attribute" exception

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function which accesses a notification hub through an IBinder, as follows:-

```
public static async Task Run(string msg, IBinder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    var genericInputMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericInputMessage>(msg);
    string devicetag = "deviceid:" + genericInputMessage.device;
    var attribute = new NotificationHubAttribute
    {
        ConnectionStringSetting = "NotificationHubConnection",
        HubName = "NotificationHubName",
        TagExpression = devicetag
    };

    IAsyncCollector<Notification> notifications = binder.Bind<IAsyncCollector<Notification>>(attribute);
    ...
    ...
}
```

This compiles and works OK when done through the Azure portal.

When I use the same code in a pre-compiled Azure function using VS2017 (version 15.3.3), and run it locally, I am getting an exception at the call to binder.Bind.

The exception given is....

```
[23/09/2017 16:47:07] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[23/09/2017 16:47:07] Exception while executing function: DataProcessor. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No binding found for attribute 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.NotificationHubAttribute'.
```

The code for my pre-compiled Azure function is as follows:-

```
public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("EventHubName", Connection = "EventHubConnection")]string msg, IBinder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    var genericInputMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericInputMessage>(msg);
    string devicetag = "deviceid:" + genericInputMessage.device;
    var attribute = new NotificationHubAttribute
    {
        ConnectionStringSetting = "NotificationHubConnection",
        HubName = "NotificationHubName",
        TagExpression = devicetag
    };

    IAsyncCollector<Notification> notifications = binder.Bind<IAsyncCollector<Notification>>(attribute);
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am using the following NuGet packages:-

[image: NuGet packages]

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Based on your description, I could reproduce this issue on my local side. I found a similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1295), you could refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may ultimately be due to the runtime not properly detecting Notification Hub usage (and thus not loading the extension). Normally, we can scan Function.json to determine what's needed - but IBinder usage is more opaque.

As a workaround, can you add function that references a Notification Hub binding? It can be Manual Trigger and doesn't need to ever actually get called.

This is related to https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1637

Comment: Added a dummy function with a Notification Hub binding and this resolved the issue for me. Thanks for the help!